How to maximize the area of the triangle?
Let $W$ be a focus of the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$. $P$ and $Q$ are two points on the ellipse such that for any position of $P$ and $Q$ on the ellipse, perimeter of $\Delta PQW$ is always constant. What is the maximum area of $\Delta PQW$?

I chose $P(\theta_1)$ and $Q(\theta_2)$ such that they are the end points of the focal chord to keep the perimeter as constant
Let $'t'$ denote the semi-perimeter
$$|SP+WP|=2a$$ $$|SQ+WQ|=2a$$
Perimeter $=PQ+WQ+WP=4a$
$$t=2a$$
$$A=\sqrt{t(t-PQ)(t-WP)(t-QW)}$$
$$A=\sqrt{-2a^4e(1+e\cos\theta_1)(1+e\cos\theta_2)(\cos\theta_1+\cos\theta_2)}$$
Also:
$$\frac{2(SP)(SQ)}{SP+SQ}=\frac{b^2}{a}$$
$$(1+e\cos\theta_1)(1+e\cos\theta_2)=\frac{b^2}{2a^2}(2+e(\cos\theta_1+\cos\theta_2))$$
$$A=ab\sqrt{-e(2+e(\cos\theta_1+\cos\theta_2))(\cos\theta_1+\cos\theta_2)}$$
Now, how do I maximize $A$ with two variables or is there any property of ellipse which can bring it to a single variable?
I also tried approaching this by this method:
$$A=\frac{1}{2}\begin{vmatrix}
a\cos\theta_1 & b\sin\theta_1 & 1\\
a\cos\theta_2 & b\sin\theta_2 & 1\\
ae & 0 & 1
\end{vmatrix}$$
$$A=\frac{ab}{2}(\sin(\theta_1-\theta_2)-e(\sin\theta_1-\sin\theta_2))$$
Here as well I faced the same issue as in previous method.
Also, what are the alternate methods to maximize this area?

There are some nice physically motivated methods presented in Mark Levi's The Mathematical Mechanic: Using Physical Reasoning to Solve Problems

Optimization in several variables relies on vector calculus. Are you familiar with that?

The area can be written as
$$
A_{WPQ}=A_{WPS}+A_{WQS}={1\over2}2ae(y_P-y_Q),
$$
hence we need to find the maximum of $y_P-y_Q$. Taking a convenient parametrization with $\phi=\angle WSP$:
$$
y_P={a(1-e^2)\over1-e\cos\phi}\sin\phi,
\quad
y_Q=-{a(1-e^2)\over1+e\cos\phi}\sin\phi,
$$
we get:
$$
y_P-y_Q={2a(1-e^2)\sin\phi\over1-e^2\cos^2\phi}.
$$
By differentiating with respect to $\phi$,
it is not difficult to show that this reaches a maximimum for $\phi=90°$, which gives the maximum area as
$$
A_\max=2a^2e(1-e^2).
$$
